# Generally what should I do to respond to a search engine bot request with error format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search-engine, bots, http-request

For example, I have an action which responds to an json ajax request on my site.

Recently I found a lot of errors caused by search engine bot request to this endpoint with `html` request.

What's the best practice for dealing with this? Should I just respond with error format or I should create a page just because that search engine bot would crawl? And I am using Rails, specific recommendations would be nicer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ever heard of `robots.txt`? AFAIK, it typically resides in Rails project's `public` folder.

Comment: @D-side Yes, I know that, I am just curious whether I should tell the search engine bot 'You are wrong' or I should fulfill it, mainly SEO wise.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice here is to deal with them with your proxy server (e.g. `nginx`). What you can do here:

- create `robots.txt` file within your `public` directory and create appropriate rules (see [here](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-and-configure-your-robots-txt-file)). However, since they're just rules, they do not have to be obeyed by any of them.
- create `nginx` rule to reject requests looking like bots using `$http_user_agent`, e.g: [Blocking all bots except a few with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337662/blocking-all-bots-except-a-few-with-nginx)